# Are enum values actually subclasses of the enum itself?

Tags: java, class, enums

So I've run across something interesting which is incredibly useful.  In an `enum` you can define an `abstract` method which each of the `enum` values is forced to provide an implementation for.  For example, the following:

```
public enum Test {

    RAWR ("Burninating the country side") {
        @Override
        public int doStuff() {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    private final String enumStuff;

    private Test(String enumStuff) {
        this.enumStuff = enumStuff;
    }

    public abstract int doStuff();

}
```

I added the private variable so you could see how it works in relation to the standard `private` constructor.

So this makes me wonder: what is `RAWR` actually, in relation to the `Test` class?  Normally, this kind of syntax would make me think that I'm defining an anonymous inner class, but that doesn't seem intuitive here, since `RAWR` is anything but anonymous.

The closest thing I can think of is that the values of an `enum` are in fact extensions of the `enum` itself, e.g.,

```
public class RAWR extends Test {
    @Override
    public int doStuff() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So, does anyone know what's *really* going on with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1)

> An enum declaration specifies a new enum type, **a special kind of class type.**
>
> [...]
>
> The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an
>   anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately
>   enclosing enum type.

The [JLS also states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3)

> For each enum constant `c` declared in the body of the declaration of `E`,
>   `E` has an implicitly declared `public static final field` of type `E` that
>   has the same name as `c`. The field has a variable initializer
>   consisting of `c`, and is annotated by the same annotations as `c`.

The `enum` type you declare is `Test`. Every enum constant you declare is an instance of a subclass of `Test`, if it has a body.

Note that `enum` types are also implicitly `final` (you wouldn't be able to subclass them). The Java Language only allows this subclassing behavior for enum constants.

Comment: So that means that the `enum` value is already a class, right?  Otherwise it would be impossible to create an anonymous class off of it.  So am I right that the values extend the base `enum` class?

Comment: @jeff Sorry, I had to step away from my pc. Let me find you the quote from the JLS. Every constant is implicitly a static field of the enum class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very powerful feature of enums, in that not only is each `enum` a fully fledged class that can have constructors, setters, getters etc but each individual member of the `enum` can have its own anonymous implementation of the main enum class.

Answer (score 1):

You actually are defining anonymous inner classes. Execute `javap -c <classFile>` on the class file of your enum to see how the enum looks when compiled.

You will see that an enum is nothing more than a normal class with public static final variables of the same type as the enum. You will also see that for each variable an anonymous inner class is assigned.

Example:

```
$ javap-c StatusCode.class

public final class de.haufe.StatusCode extends java.lang.Enum<de.haufe.StatusC                                                                                        ode> {
    public static final de.haufe.StatusCode CREATED;

    public static final de.haufe.StatusCode BAD_REQUEST;

    public static final de.haufe.StatusCode UNAUTHORIZED;

    public static final de.haufe.StatusCode NOT_FOUND;

    public static final de.haufe.StatusCode PRECONDITION_FAILED;

    public static final de.haufe.StatusCode UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE;

    public static final de.haufe.StatusCode UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY;

    public static final de.haufe.StatusCode LOCKED;

    public static final de.haufe.StatusCode INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    public static de.haufe.StatusCode[] values();
}

// more stuff
```

So this is not the best example because none of the enum value implements a method but you may get an idea what an enum actually is.

Answer (score 1):

If you've ever used `enum`s in generics you will have come across `E extends Enum<E>` which is the *right* way of defining the type of an `enum`. It's a little weird but once you get your head around it you can see that it is saying that an enum actually extends an `Enum` (note the different case) of itself. So essentially yes, **all `enum`s in the group seem to extend the base declaring class** but the base declaring class is actually an `Enum` - sort of.

BTW - You can also make `enum`s implement an interface:

```
interface Something {
    int getValue();
}

enum It implements Something {
    One,
    Two,
    Three;

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return ordinal();
    }
}
```